# Facebook Share not working in 2016

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, share

By way of a prelude I should say that I have found numerous instances where this question has been asked on StackOverflow in the past, but the answers are either now depricated thanks to FB's insistance on deprecating methods every year or so, or answers that are so opaque (usually under the guise of being 'hints') as to be no more helpful than FB's own documentation, which seems to resist fully worked examples as a matter of principal. So here is the question again for 2016 conditions.

My level of knowledge with Javascript is modest. This is what I have so far. Plenty of OpenGraph tags that FB validates as ok, e.g.

```
<meta property="fb:admins"             content="12345..." />
<meta property="fb:app_id"             content="67890..."/>
<meta property="og:site_name"          content="Renegades Alliance" />
<meta property="og:url"                content="http://www.renegadesalliance.eu" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="Renegades Alliance" />
```

...and so on, all validating. Then in the header I have FB's SDK as follows:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '123...',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.6'
    });
  };

  FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
}, function(response){});

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Note in the middle there I added the FB.ui function which I got from FB documentation as necessary to open the Share dialogue on my page - the goal of this work, although it didn't actually say where to put it, so I hope that's the right area.

Lastly I need some sort of link to trigger the opening of the dialogue. I will be putting this around a custom version of a Facebook icon, so it needs to be some sort of hyperlink. I have tried everything I can think of, like:

```
<a onClick="FB.ui()" href="#"> Will this work?</a>
```

...but nothing even remotely works. I have been working on this for 2 weeks and it's completely frustrating. I did have this working on another site about 3 years ago but FB changed it and everything broke again. I really am at my wits end trying to do what should be a simple thing here, so any accurate and up to date insight / assistance would be immensely appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Keep your opengraph tags**

Right after opening `<BODY>` tag, put:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6&appId=1536573183291630";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

*(note that my language are 'pt_BR'. Change to your language)*

and anywhere you want the button to be displayed:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://primeiralinha.com.br/home2/noticia_online.php?noticia_online=367" data-layout="button_count" data-mobile-iframe="true"></div>
```

data-href attribute is what you should change to your url.

For more information, see the Share Button docs:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

EDIT:

consider this code:(copy whole code and save it as `try.html` or whatever you like with `htm` or `html` extension)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your Website Title</title>
    <!-- You can use Open Graph tags to customize link previews.
    Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters -->
    <meta property="og:url"           content="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" />
    <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title"         content="Your Website Title" />
    <meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
    <meta property="og:image"         content="http://www.your-domain.com/path/image.jpg" />
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6&appId=1536573183291630";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <!-- Your share button code -->
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://primeiralinha.com.br/home2/noticia_online.php?noticia_online=367" data-layout="button_count" data-mobile-iframe="true"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

It should work

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that, but it didn't work. No button appears, even though I followed your instructions exactly - well, I added a closing </DIV> to the button code :). In any event, I am trying to make this work with a custom link since as I said ' I will be putting this around a custom version of a Facebook icon'. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: Hi. I tried the code you sent me, changing only the info in the meta tags to reflect the real environment. AGain, it's not working. See here: http://www.renegadesalliance.eu/test.html and check the source code. I can get no button to appear.

Comment: Curious. It works in IE10 too, but not in Firefox 46 (which I'm developing with). I say it 'works': I mean the button appears. It doesn't pick up any of the meta og information to populate the dialogue with, and I can't use it with a custom button, but it's an interesting if inconsistent result, but rather underlines my problem rather than solves it.

Comment: skipping the browser problem... in this exact case, _the button will catch og data_ from `data-href` attribute source. I think that the problem was solved and now demands a properly [og config](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-properties) on the source `data-href`

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts IonS. The difficulty with blaming it on the config of the og data is that Facebooks own scraper certifies that that are no problems with the og data. Unable to solve this problem (again - the FB problem keeps happening year on year) I decided to look for a JQuery plugin that might address the question. There are hndreds out there, but I eventually settled for a very excellent plugin called 'goodshare' that I found here: https://github.com/enjoyiacm/goodshare.js Thank you for your thoughts & your time on what seems to be an insoluble problem at my level of knowledge.

Comment: You are welcome, it was a pleasure!
Here goes one more THOUGHT: When working to improve something, like facebook are doing, you'll always have to do updates to the code, the question is: The guys of Facebook could keep the support for older implementations..

Comment: I agree completely Ions. It's a problem. Thank you!